Name spelling for Deutsche Post Nachsendeservice
I am trying to fill out the Nachsendeservice by Deutsche Post, and my surname has a special character that does not exist in German (ç). Besides that, people often mispell my first name as well.
On the instructions to fill out my name it's written:

Bitte geben Sie hier den vollständigen Namen (laut gültigem Ausweisdokument) und alternative Namensschreibweisen der Person ein, deren Post nachgesandt werden soll.

Translated to:

Please enter the full name (as per valid ID document) and alternative spelling of the name of the person whose mail is to be forwarded.

However, there is no indication of how I should do it. There is no extra space for the "alternative spellings".
Any tips on how to do it to avoid that I miss any mail due to a different spelling?


[…] However, there is no indication of how I should do it. There is no extra space for the "alternative spellings". […]


I searched for "Nachsendeauftrag" "alternative Namensschreibweisen" and found a discussion in the Usenet group de.etc.post asking the same question.
The questioner settled for adding “a person” (Weitere Personen hinzufügen) for each and every alternative spelling.
Apparently it worked out for him.
From a technical standpoint this procedure is dumb.
However, what’s intuitive to the computer programmer – writing a regular expression such as A[[=ï=]]ss?ata [[=Ç=]]ak[[=ı=]]r – is not intuitive to the general population, so “1 spelling = 1 person” might be indeed the expected method.


[…] Besides that, people often mispell my first name as well. […]

And people misspell the word misspell.
That’s their problem.
If the misspelled name isn’t backed by official documentation (even authorities occasionally produce incorrect IDs) I would refrain from entering it; but you do you.

[…] Any tips on how to do it to avoid that I miss any mail due to a different spelling?

There’s nothing you can do (unless you would like to change your name and civil‑law sex [the latter regarding firstname]).
